# What does GTK_WINDOW(window)->allow_shrink = TRUE mean in c?

Tags: c, gtk

I'm just getting started with gtk,anyone knows what this means?

```
GTK_WINDOW(window)->allow_shrink = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

It means the user can resize the window to smaller dimensions than were specified on creation of the window.  GTK+ has an excellent reference, [a quick search is all you need](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-policy).

Answer (score 1):

According to the GTK docs, something you shouldn't do:

> If allow_shrink is TRUE, the user can
>   shrink the window so that its children
>   do not receive their full size
>   request; this is basically a bad
>   thing, because most widgets will look
>   wrong if this happens. Furthermore
>   GTK+ has a tendency to re-expand the
>   window if size is recalculated for any
>   reason. The upshot is that
>   allow_shrink should always be set to
>   FALSE.

See [this page](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-policy) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If TRUE, the window has no mimimum size. Setting this to TRUE is 99% of the time a bad idea.

Default value: FALSE

If allow_shrink is TRUE, the user can shrink the window so that its children do not receive their full size request; this is basically a bad thing, because most widgets will look wrong if this happens. Furthermore GTK+ has a tendency to re-expand the window if size is recalculated for any reason. The upshot is that allow_shrink should always be set to FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the `GTK_WINDOW(window)` part, then I imagine it is casting/adjusting the pointer to obtain a pointer to a `struct` type for a window object that contains a variable called `allow_shrink`.